# C# circular reference between owner and owned object, indirectly?

Tags: c#, .net

I was wondering if my code below has possible circular references. I am not exactly sure about how Garbage Collection works in C#. I added the line numbers for clarity to responders. **Line 16**  in **mainForm.cs** worries me because, as you can see, VerticalText is an item in the container and has a ('reference' I guess) to the container that it is in. It gets tricky because my item/object is owned by UI element Panel and data persistece element List<> The other possible circular reference is in **line 14** of **mainForm.cs** where the owned member variable gets a pointer to its owner.

I did my research, before posting this question, only to come up with ambiguous answers. This code is part of a large program and it works. Even stepping through with the debugger I can see that this VerticalText object deletes its self in **line 24** of **VerticalText.cs** because when debugger steps on line 25, the count of the List<> is decremented by 1.

I am also including additional questions, which may raise subtle issues, in the form of comments on **lines 5** and **25** in **VerticalText.cs** which are not as important but would be helpful.
  This is a word pad style application that has rotatable text represented as instances of VerticalText class, each that lives in TransparentPanel class. Each instance has several buttons, one of which allows it to delete itself. The point is to communicate with the Panel and the storage container (**List<>**) of this instance to have it removed. Please let me know if my code creates memory leaks or circular references. I hope no one marks this as duplicate and instead spends the time to give me an answer. Thank you.

```
1  // mainForm.cs
2  // Member vars. are 'public' just for this example. In program, they are private with public properties
3  namespace My_Note
4  {
5     public partial class MainForm : Form
6     {
7        private List<VerticalText>m_verticalTextList = new List<VerticalText>(); // Container of VerticalText
8        
9        // transparentPanel is a 'Panel' in the 'MainForm', it can hold several instances of VerticalText
10       transparentPanel_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
11       {
12          VerticalText nextText = new VerticalText(e);
13          nextText.OwnerTranspPanel = transparentPanel; // trying to pass a 'pointer/reference'
14          nextText.OwnerRichTextBox = richTextBox; // trying to pass a 'pointer/reference'
15          nextText.OwnerBackPanel = backPanel; // trying to pass a 'pointer/reference'
16          nextText.OwnerVerticalTextList = m_verticalTextList; /* pointer/reference to the object
17                                                                  that will own me (Good or bad?) */
18
19          m_verticalTextList.Add(nextText);
20          transparentPanel.Controls.Add(nextText.MoveButton);
21          transparentPanel.Controls.Add(nextText.OptionsButton);
22          transparentPanel.Controls.Add(nextText.DeleteButton);
23          transparentPanel.Controls.Add(nextText.RotateButton);
24       }
25       // Some other code...
26    }
26 }

1  // VerticalText.cs
2  // Member vars. are 'public' just for this example. In program, they are private with public properties
3  namespace My_Note
4  {
5     class VerticalText // should this be public, private, internal, or can it just stay the way it is?
6     {
7        public TransparentPanel OwnerTransparentPanel // 'pointer/reference' to my owner's other object
8        public RichTextBox OwnerRichTextBox; // 'pointer/reference' to my owner's other object
9        public Panel OwnerBackPanel; // 'pointer/reference' to my owner's other object
10       public List<VerticalText>OwnerVerticalTextList; /* 'pointer/reference' to my owner's other object
11                                                          which also contains me (this). */
12       private Button m_deleteButton = new Button(); // One of several buttons
13
14       m_deleteButton_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
15       {
16          foreach (VerticalText v in OwnerVerticalTextList)
17          {
18             if (v == this)
19             {
20                OwnerTranspPanel.Controls.Remove(m_moveButton);
21                OwnerTranspPanel.Controls.Remove(m_optionsButton);
22                OwnerTranspPanel.Controls.Remove(m_deleteButton);
23                OwnerTranspPanel.Controls.Remove(m_rotateButton);
24                OwnerVerticalTextList.Remove(v); // Am I allowed to delete myself here?
25                return; // If I deleted myself, then why does this still work?
26             }
27          }
28       }
29       // Some other code...
30    }
31 }
```

Comment: The way I use to avoid circular references and to have a pointer to the parent class in a child class is using `WeakReference`.  You can have a variable that is the `WeakReference` and a property that return the real object. You have more detailed information in  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Very good. I guess it is called explicit declaration. I guess this applies to parent-child relationships as well as objects that are not directly related to each other.

Comment: 1. Use memory profiler to check if your app has memory leak or no. It is the only way.
2. Why do you worry about circular references?

Comment: Ed.ward, I'm not even sure if I should be worried about a circular reference. I am used to Objective-C's Automatic Reference Counting, where a circular reference can become a memory issue. I was just not sure about memory management in C#. But I am starting to see that Garbage Collector is much more efficient and reliable than I thought. Thanks for all the advice though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've got there is a weak reference.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404247%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

When you "forget" the VerticalText object, it becomes unreachable by your code, which the garbage collector will clean it up even if it contains weak references to other objects.

Comment: Works for me. Two thumbs up!